# How to add button that pass value to textbox in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios9, swift4

I'm new to xcode. I am creating converter app using decimalpad keyboard. I need to add button that have value (-). When ii click this button, this value should appear in my textbox. How to do it.

Comment: It would help to learn the basics, there are some nice videos, start from the beginning. Refer - https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-11-apps-with-swift/id1309275316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a tutorial on starting iOS app development, such as those provided by AppCoda or Hacking With Swift.

You will need to add at least a `UIButton` and a `UILabel` to your app's main `viewController`. You will then need to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+drag these to your `viewController` code to create an `IBOutlet`, so the button and label can be accessed by the code.

Then use code like this:

```
// The Interface Builder Outlets
 @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

// The Interface Builder Action for the button
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    myLabel.text = "Your text here!"
}
```

---

Alternatively, I could be misunderstanding your needs. If you want a custom button on the keyboard to input a "-" symbol, you will need to create a custom keyboard extension and set it as the `inputView` of the `UITextField`. You would then need code to parse the text of your `UITextField` to get the result you need.

There is a tutorial on this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html).